# Minimum steps from download to execute on OS X?

Tags: macos

I want to run a compiled program on OS X with minimal user interaction following download.

On Windows, you can download a .exe, and choose "run" directly, so that's 1 click.

I'm not very familiar with OS X, and am not sure if I need a PKG, a DMG, or if there's some way to do the equivalent of the "single shot" .exe.

I'm not concerned about the application installing correctly, etc. In fact, it would be desirable if it could delete itself after executing, but this is not a requirement. If the user needs to run it again, they can repeat the download and run process.

I understand running programs downloaded from the Internets is dangerous..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical way to distribute apps that don't need an installer is a DMG. However, I've also seen examples where the .app folder is put straight in a zip file. If you download such a zip file which contains nothing but an .app, it seems Safari will automatically extract the zip file and replace it with the .app. The user then just needs to run the app, either from Finder or directly from the Download dialog, and confirm the question about running downloaded code.

Other browsers don't seem to do the extraction automatically, but even so it's pretty straightforward as extracting a zip file is as easy as running the app itself.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the fewest steps for the end user, and also has the nice feature of being really simple to implement.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a so-called "internet-enabled" disk image: Safari will then copy the contents into the download folder and trash the image, without the user having to fiddle with mounting and unmounting it. `hdiutil internet-enable -yes YourDiskImage.dmg`

But I would probably go with a simple zip file instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not what you want, but… I'm not 100% sure of that, so in case it *is* what you want:

The equivalent of a "single-shot .exe" is a single-shot executable. You don't actually have to have a .app bundle; you can launch a command-line executable from Finder (or from the Dock, or the "open" command, or whatever) and it'll run by opening a window in Terminal. The output will look something like this:

```
Last login: Wed May 23 18:52:23 on ttys000
MyMac:~me$ /Users/me/Downloads/myexecutable ; exit;
logout
[Process completed]
```

That should be familiar to anyone who builds and runs command-line executables in Windows.

If you're using Xcode, just create a "Command Line Tool" instead of a "Cocoa Application". If you're not using Xcode, it's just a matter of compiling the same way you would on Linux.

If you actually need to create a GUI window, interact with the menubar, send and receive Apple Events, or anything like that, this is not the right answer. But if you're looking for something quick and dirty for yourself or other tech-savvy users, it may be.